# How to transfer only certain amount of flowfile?

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I  want  to  get  certain amount  of  flowfile  from  previous  queue, put  it  into  flowfileList and  if  list   size  is equal   to  this amount  I  will  start  to  transfer   them but  when  I  try  to  transfer  them  it  doesn't  put anything in neither success queue  nor  failure  queue. Here  is  my code,   what  should  I change to make  this work  properly?

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import groovy.lang.*
def flowFile = session.get()
name=flowFile.getAttribute("realName")
count=flowFile.getAttribute("count")
filename=flowFile.getAttribute("filename")
 value= count as Double;
def numb=Math.round(value)
def List<FlowFile> flowFiles=new ArrayList<>();
flowFiles.add(flowFile)


if(flowFiles.size()==numb){
for(FlowFile f  in flowFiles){
session.transfer(f,REL_SUCCESS)


}
flowFiles.clear();
}
session.remove(flowFile)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the code in the question is for ExecuteScript processor with groovy language.

---

The problem in your code against idea:

The script and all variables declared in it are present only during each processing.

Every time you take one flow file from incoming queue `flowFile = session.get()`, put it into the local list variable `flowFiles.add(flowFile)`, and then you remove the file `session.remove(flowFile)`. Finally at the end of the script all variables are disappeared (including the `flowFiles` list).

The condition `if(flowFiles.size()==numb){...}` always returns false if you have `numb>1` because `flowFiles.size()` always equals to `1` in your algorithm.

---

If you want to transfer flow files only when exect number of files are present in the incoming queue, the code could be like this:

```
def flowFile = session.get()
if (!flowFile) return
def numb=(flowFile.getAttribute("count") as Double).round()

//we already got one file, let's get the rest NUMB-1 files from incoming queue
def flowFiles = session.get(numb-1)
if (!flowFiles || flowFiles.size()<numb-1){
    //rollback everything we got from incoming queue
    session.rollback()
}else{
    //transfer first and other files to success
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
    session.transfer(flowFiles, REL_SUCCESS)
}
```

but IMHO this logic has no sence.

Comment: How  does session get  flowfilelist in nifi,     for  exmple  if  it  hsould   get  5   flowfile   and  thre  are  10    files  in suceess  queue  it  will   reitreive  last  file   flowfile?

Comment: Is  it  neseccary  for flowfiles   to  be in  process sessions  i  mean  if  i  place  them in  flowfile  list  they can't  be  processed bacuase relative  processession was  removed ?

Comment: I  have  tried   you  example  too   but  it  nor  puts  anything  in success  relationship  neither   trows exception

Comment: logically  it  is   right  but  here is   one more   thing i want to  know , is  it  possible that  after  several rollbacks  processsession  can't   recognize   how to transfer flowfiles   because  general  session is  crushed?